# NSImageView doesn't set image property after an image dragged in

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimageview

I have an NSImageView that I placed in my NIB that I drag an image into. The image appears and displays, but when my code calls `[imageView image]`, I get a NULL object.

Comment: Did you double-check that imageView isn't nil before you call it?  This can happen if the outlet isn't hooked up in the xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for drag and dropping to work, you need to set the `NSImageView` as editable, either in Interface Builder or programmatically by using the method `setEditable:`. However, you've said the dropped image appears, so you've obviously enabled editing somewhere. The only other reason `[imageView image]` would return `nil` is if the `NSImageView` wasn't correctly connected to the object referencing it. You can check the connection by opening the `.h` file that the `IBOutlet` is defined and clicking on the filled-in dot to the left of the declaration.  If the dot is unfilled, that means the connection hasn't been made and you need to go back into Interface Builder and make the connection. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF6b0.png) is an example of what you'll see when clicking a filled-in dot.